# Lightdm + Cinnamon: Missing System Tray Icons

Tags: lightdm, 20.10, cinnamon

If I use gdm3, the problem does not appear, instead if I use lightdm, the problem appear until I restart cinnamon:

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I solve the problem?

EDIT: I have installed these two in the following manner:

```
sudo apt install lightdm  # choosed lightdm in the interactive prompt
sudo apt install cinnamon-desktop-environment
```

And then rebooted.

Comment: How did you installed Cinnamon? Are you sure that you have full installation of it?

Comment: Ok, I have edited the question.

Comment: Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over the same problem today -- switched from gdm3 to lightdm, to get `nxserver` in ubuntu-22.04 to a working state.

In my case I had to kill `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-application/indicator-application-service` to get all system-tray icons to get displayed correctly.